# Append new excel files to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a code that takes all files from dir and create dataframe, then saves it to xls. How do I make it to just append new files instead of creating new dataframe each time from all files?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import time

path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test'  # path
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsm")) # advisable to use os.path.join as this makes concatenation OS independent

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name='Rank', header= 2, usecols=['Model', 'HK']) for f in all_files)
concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
concatenated_df = concatenated_df.set_index('Model')

#Save dataframe to excel file
concatenated_df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\output.xlsx')
```

Comment: you would have to somehow remeber which files you alread appended - and it would need to keep filenames in some file or database. Or you would have to get file time for all files and compare with file time of excel. And then you will know which files are new. `os.stat(path).st_ctime` (creation time) or `.st_atime` (access time) or `.st_mtime` (modification time)? Some values may not work correctly on some systems.

Comment: @furas i have another code that prints for me all files from directory, so i should make a list from it and then check for new files and append them?

Comment: if you have old list and new list then you can compare it - and then you can get new files. But it may need to remeber old list - save on exit program and load it again at the start.